# Скрыть запускаемый процесс

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Запускаю скрипт через `QProcess`, код:

```
void analysis::on_pB_start_clicked()
{   
    QString file = ui->lE_path->text();
    QProcess analyse;
    QString cArg;
    cArg="/tmp/test.py -f " + file;
    analyse.start("xfce4-terminal", QStringList() << "--command" << "python3 "+cArg);
    analyse.waitForFinished();
    analyse.close();    
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно `скрыть` (выполнение в фоновом режиме) терминал `xfce4-terminal`?

Пробовал подставить некоторые [аргументы](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/xfce4-terminal/xfce4-terminal.1.ru.html), но ни чего не выходит.

Большое спасибо.

Comment: так не запускайте терминал. и не нужно будет ничего скрывать. запускайте непосредственно питон с его аргументами.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, сделал так: `analyse.start("python3 "+cArg);` - работает как надо.

Comment: ну так оно и должно работать как нужно.